# How to count unique occurrences with criteria in excel

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I'm using the below array formula to count the unique occurrences of text in column C using the agent name in column G as the reference. This is giving me multiple issues.

```
=SUM( --(FREQUENCY(IF(G3:G100000 = J5,MATCH(C3:C100000,C3:C100000,0)),ROW(C3:C100000) - ROW(C3) + 1) > 0))
```

1. Depending on the data set I'm using multiple agents will return a #N/A result and I can't figure out why.
2. Each dataset I'm using is 20k to 30k lines, so the formulas take a long time to process.

Any ideas how I could do this faster or better? Also any ideas why some agents get bad returns?

Comment: If any agents have a row with a blank cell in column C, you're going to get an `#N/A`. Also, are you against the idea of a user-defined function?

Comment: does `=COUNTIF(C:C,G1)` (and drag downwards) did what you need?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are looking for the number of unique combinations of columns C and G.

- Create a pivot table and check the box to add this data to the data model.
- Drag both column headers to the Rows section, also drag one (of those same two) into the the values section.
- click on the the field in the values section > value field settings > summarize values by > choose Distinct Count.  This removes all duplicates.

  - Click the Row Labels filter and uncheck the blanks.

You can drop in new data then right-click on the pivot and refresh to see the new results.  See the image.  [image: Screenshot]